# Using continuity to prove a set is open.

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have a rather straight forward example / proof that I would like critique on.

Prove that $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x>1, y>0\}$ is open.

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y) = x+y$. This function is continuous as it is a sum of two continuous polynomial functions.

We have that $S = f^{-1}((1,\infty))$. Since $(1,\infty)$ is open, and $f$ is continuous, then by theorem, $S$ is also open.

I am not sure if this proof is correct - my confusion is dealing with multiple restrictions on the set ($x > 1$ and $y > 0$). Could I get some critique on this? Perhaps another example? Am I wrong in my proof, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in your proof:

The preimage of $(1,\infty)$ is not $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x>1, y>0\}$

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. I am unsure how to determine a function whose preimage gives me "what I want". Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps f(x,y) = x-1 is a better function?

Comment: @TimelordViktorious $f(3,-1)=2$ but $(3,-1)\not\in S$

Comment: As a variation of solution of Henry W., the function $f(x,y)=\min\{x,y+1\}$ would be continuous and satisfy your desired preimage $S = f^{-1}((1,\infty))$

Answer (score 1):

An easier proof would be to notice that
$$ S = {]1, \rightarrow]} \times {]0,\rightarrow]}
$$
is the product of two open intervals, and hence open.

Alternatively, define $f(x,y) = \min(x-1,y)$. Evidently $f$ is continuous, and $S = f^{-1}[{]0,\rightarrow]}]$